# Update Android ListActivity when list data changes?

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I wanted to know how to refresh a `ListActivity` when I change/add data to it.

I first thought that `ListAdapter` would know when the list is changes, but when I have added elements to the list there is no update on the `ListActivity`, only when I close the ListActivity and reopen it again I see the changes occur.

So I searched for any method such as: `update(), refesh()` or something like that, but there is none.
It seems I haven't gotten the concept, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using an `ArrayAdapter`, manipulate the contents of the list through the adapter -- do not touch the underlying list. There are `add()`, `insert()`, and `remove()` methods on `ArrayAdapter`.

If you are using a `CursorAdapter`, run a `requery()` on the `Cursor`.

Comment: I use ArrayAdapter and I update record. How can I refresh ListView?

Comment: This, of course, is no longer recommended, as `requery()` is performed on the UI thread. If you happen to stumble across this post, you should consider using a `Loader` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Try **ArrayAdapter:notifyDataSetChanged**
[Google docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: Just a note, that doesn't work if there isn't any observers to attached to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do this `setListAdapter(listAdapter);`